# Python: Equation coefficients from numpy.poly1d as separate variables

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get  polynomial equation coefficients from numpy.poly1d as separate variables?

So far I have this code where I get the equation. I need to define coef. 0.08669; 0.158 and 5.743 from the equation as variables, so that I could use the equation with these coefficients in calculation in new dataframe column.

```
x = df['Height']
y = df['Age']
model = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 2))
print(model)
​
def polyfit(x, y, degree):
    results = {}
    coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, degree)
    p = np.poly1d(coeffs)
    #calculate r-squared
    yhat = p(x)
    ybar = np.sum(y)/len(y)
    ssreg = np.sum((yhat-ybar)**2)
    sstot = np.sum((y - ybar)**2)
    results['r_squared'] = ssreg / sstot
​
    return results
​
polyfit(x, y, 2)
print(type(model))
         2
0.08669 x - 0.158 x + 5.743
<class 'numpy.poly1d'>
```

Not sure about the best way creating a new columns based on the equation, but I plan it to look something like this:

```
a = 0.08669 b = 0.158 c = 5.743

df.loc['NewColumn'] = 0.08669 * (df['Height']**2) - 0.158 * * df['Height'] + 5.743
```